# Can an institution "attest to its highest academic standards"? Is that kind of attesting something only a person can do?

Tags: meaning, verb-agreement

My full quotation is for a formal letter to a university president, congratulating her on becoming president.

"Under your leadership, I believe that Anytown University will continue to attest to its highest academic standards and contribute to the further advancement of higher education."

Is this correct, or can attesting only be done by a person?

Comment: I don't think "attest" is the correct word here.  Which sense of "attest" did you have in mind?

Comment: I didn't - this is a translation I would very much like to improve, but I would like some justification. "It doesn't sound right" lacks a certain rigor.

Comment: Perhaps in that case it would be best to refer to the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attest means to vouch for or provide evidence to something which I don't think the president would be doing. **Attain** should be the word used here if the highest status hasn't been achieved yet or **maintain** if otherwise.

```
"Under your leadership, I believe the Anytown University will continue to maintain its highest academic standards and contribute to the further advancement of higher education."
```

**or**

```
"Under your leadership, I believe the Anytown University will attain its highest academic standards and contribute to the further advancement of higher education."
```

Comment: Isn't 'continue to maintain' redundant in this context? Simply 'maintain' says the same thing, no?

Comment: Nicely caught Jim, it certainly is a tautological phrase.